# How to fix this NullPointer in my ViewList Selected Item Action Listener?

Tags: java, javafx

I am attempting to write a listener for when a new item is selected on a ListView Node. But the problem is I get a NPE when I run the application. From looking at it I am assuming that this may be being thrown because the list is empty upon run time, but I have no clue how to fix it.

Update 1:
From further investigation, with a btn action listener I am writing. When I tried to access the selected item, I was thrown a null pointer exception. Work around was wrapping it with a try/catch, which ultimately fixed it. Will try something similar with viewList and see if it will work

Update 2: 
try/catch(NPE) workaround worked for the viewList action Listener

Code at Line 186: **ListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new...**

```
listView = new ListView<BusinessCard>();
observableList = FXCollections.observableList(cardModel.getCards());
//cardModel.getCards() -> ArrayList<BusinessCards>

// ListView Listener, changes text fields for the selected B.C in ViewLsit
            listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<BusinessCard>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends BusinessCard> arg0, BusinessCard oldval,BusinessCard newVal) {
                    if(newVal != null) setDataFields(newVal.getUI());       
                }
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. This is a specific question about a JavaFX problem.

Comment: Line 186 does not consist of 10 lines. Which one is 186?

Comment: For `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...` to throw this exception `listView` would need to be `null` (either that or one of the chained method calls return `null`, which doesn't happen with the standard `ListView`)

Comment: The question is valid and it is not duplicate of "What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()... and the view list was empty, null was being thrown. Which is said to be a behavior in the documentation

Workaround:

```
// ListView Listener, changes text fields for the selected B.C in ViewList

            listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<BusinessCard>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends BusinessCard> arg0, BusinessCard oldval,BusinessCard newVal) {
                    if(newVal == null) return;
                    setDataFields(newVal.getUI());      
                }
            });
```